# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2 and app crashing after that

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I saw other answers and they got solved by adding itemcount in the listview but I am still getting this error. I am not getting this error for the same code I had for adding images.
In this I am using image picker to upload a video to a list and present it in listview and then upload to firebase

Add_video_screen:

```
class _addVideoState extends State<addVideo> {
  bool uploading = false;
  double val = 0;
  CollectionReference? vidRef;
  firebase_storage.Reference? ref;
  File? video;
  VideoPlayerController? videoPlayerController;

  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future pickVideo(ImageSource source) async {
    final Video = await picker.pickVideo(source: source);

    video = File(Video!.path);

    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(video!)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
        videoPlayerController!.play();
      });
  }

  List<File> _video = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add video'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                uploading = true;
              });

              uploadFile().whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop());
            },
            child: Text(
              'Upload Video',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _video.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return index == 0
                ? Center(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          !uploading ? chooseVideo() : null;
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Test',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        )),
                  )
                : AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,

                    // child: VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController!),
                    child: VideoPlayer(VideoPlayerController.file(_video[index])
                      ..initialize().then((_) {
                        setState(() {});
                        videoPlayerController!.play();
                      })),
                  );
          }),
    );
  }

  chooseVideo() async {
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

    final pickedFile = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _video.add(File(pickedFile!.path));
    });
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(pickedFile!.path))
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
        videoPlayerController!.play();
      });
    if (pickedFile.path == null) retrieveLostData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are showing an ElevatedButton for index == 0. so your index for accessing _video starts from 1 so you have to decrease 1 index to stay in the right range.

try replace this line:

```dart
child: VideoPlayer(VideoPlayerController.file(_video[index - 1])
```

Comment: I did that but still, it is not displaying video, and as soon as I add a video then the emulator crashes and closes. Only thing on debug console "Lost connection to device."